# Has anyone used Crispr/Cas to induce a knock-in in MEF cells?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

Does anyone have experience with the CRISPR/CAS9 platform performed on MEF? Or does anyone recall any relevant articles?

Comment: Is this the paper you are looking for? http://genesdev.cshlp.org/content/27/23/2602.long

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://genesdev.cshlp.org/content/27/23/2602.long) paper:

> We chose to test for Cas9-driven targeted mutagenesis on the
>   endogenous Trp53 gene in mouse embryonic fibroblasts (MEFs), a cell
>   line in which the biology of p53 has been thoroughly characterized and
>   where the gene is structurally intact.

Furthermore:

> Seventy-two hours post-transduction, cells were cultured in the
>   presence or absence of Nutlin-3a, a specific inhibitor of the MDM2–p53
>   interaction (Tovar et al. 2006). Cells were scored for the fraction of
>   GFP+ cells after 4 d of Nutlin-3a exposure using flow cytometry (Fig.
>   2B). Nutlin-3a potently activates a p53-dependent anti-proliferative
>   cellular response, which strongly and specifically selects for any
>   cells with disrupted Trp53 function (Efeyan et al. 2007). Much like
>   MLP-p53.1224 infected cells, the pQCiG-p53 GFP+ cells were rapidly
>   enriched for in the presence of Nutlin-3a, suggesting that
>   CRISPR-mediated gene disruption had initially occurred in at least a
>   proportion of the initial Cas9-expressing cells.